# Except + gerund or infitive

Tags: licensing, complementation, infinitive-clauses, gerund-clauses

## 1

The graduate student had nothing in mind except **finishing** his thesis.

## 2

The mason will not do any work except **giving** the order.

Both sentences use -ing of verb finish and give. I know these sentences are grammatically correct.
But I have two doubt here.

1.
What if we use infinitive after except "The mason will not do any work except **to give** the order". Does the use of infinitive makes it incorrect?

2. Are these Participle **finishing** and **giving** used as a gerund or as a noun?

Answer (score 2):

1. *Except* may take an infinitival clause in this case, because what is “excepted” is a complement of the verb *do*, and *do* can in this case be ‘recategorized’ as an auxiliary taking an infinitive complement. However, it should be an ‘unmarked’ infinitive, one without *to*:

   > <sup>ok</sup>The mason did not give the order.
   >   <sup>ok</sup>The mason did everything except give the order.
   >   <sup>ok</sup>The mason will not do any work except give the order.

   With another verb, however, this won’t work—*finish*, for instance does not take infinitival complements, with or without *to*:

   > <sup>ok</sup>The mason did not finish repairing the wall.
   >   <sup>?</sup>  The mason did not finish (to) repair the wall.
   >   <sup>ok</sup>The mason did not finish anything except repairing the wall.
   >   <sup>?</sup> The mason did not finish anything except (to) repair the wall.

   Note that I mark these ‘improper’ infinitivals with ‘?’. You are likely to encounter them in unprepared speech, because in speech people don’t have time to construct complex thoughts perfectly; but they should be avoided in writing. (And to tell the truth, even if you do use them most people won’t notice, or care.)
2. The *-ing* forms here act as *gerunds*. In traditional grammar, a *gerund* is, by definition, an *-ing* form which acts as a noun and a verb at the same time; a more precise description would be that a *gerund* is a verb in its *-ing* form heading a clause which acts as a noun.

---

<sup>?</sup>  <sub>marks an utterance as dubiously acceptable.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I get your point. But can you please elaborate "complement rule"(when we can use infinitive after "except") with some more example.

Comment: @starun008 There is no general rule. Each individual verb selects its own set of complement forms, and you have to learn them verb by verb.

Comment: What about "The mason did everything except *giving* the order"?